# accessing the calling function's variables

Tags: python, variables, scope

The following code

```
class Foo(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print(main.func_code.co_varnames)
        for item in main.func_code.co_varnames:
            eval(item)

def main():
    a = 1
    b = Foo()
    b.do_something()

main()
```

will print

```
('a', 'b')
```

along with an error message ending with

```
name 'a' is not defined
```

Somehow a Foo object is able to get the names of another function's local variables, but cannot do anything with them.  How can I fix that?

BACKGROUND.  This question is for debugging purposes.  I want to be able to display information about variables that are created in my code.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [`inspect.currentframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) to get a stack frame object
- Move up the call stack by 1 frame with the `f_back` attribute
- Access that frame's local variables through the `f_locals` attribute

```
import inspect

def get_variables():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print(frame.f_locals)
```

Usage:

```
def main():
    a = 1
    b = 'hello world'

    get_variables()

main()
# output: {'b': 'hello world', 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one step closer!  But actually, I want the id of the variables...  I looked at the documentation and tried various things but don't see how to get this type of information.

Comment: @Antoine Variables don't have an "id". If you're looking for the id of the value _inside_ a variable, you can use the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function.

Comment: Thanks again, another step closer! Now I am able to get the id of the value inside the variable `a` (using eval), which is an integer, but I have a problem with `b`, since Python tries to evaluate `id(<__main__.Foo object at 0x10dbc15d0>)` and it can't.  Is changing `__repr__` of the class Foo the only way to get the id?

Comment: @Antoine I don't understand what you're using `eval` for? Just use `id(get_variables()['b'])`.

Comment: Of course! I was thinking too complicated...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The local variables are defined for the function. So as long as the function is defined, the interpreter "knows" that there will be 2 local variables, named `a` and `b`. Useful for memory allocation, when the function will be called. Think of it as a blueprint.

Then, when you try to `eval` some string, it will do it using the context (`locals()` and `globals()`) of where the `eval` lies.
You do not have any `a` in that scope. Therefore, it fails, as it is not defined.